# Trying to convert string compare with Generic

Tags: c#, generics, compareto

I have a code that works well to compare a list of strings as below. Now I want to convert that in to a generic, I have tried converting the same code in to generic but I am getting errors despite of many attempts to correct it. As I am new to generics, I need an expert hand to guide me to what I am doing wrong.

```
public class BaseComparer<T> : IComparer<T>, IDisposable where T : IBaseComparer<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, T[]> Value;

    public BaseComparer()
    {
        Value = new Dictionary<T, T[]>();
    }

        public int Compare(T lhs, T rhs)
        {
            if (lhs.Equals(rhs))
                return 0;

            T[] strFirst, strSecond;

            if (!Value.TryGetValue(lhs, out strFirst))
            {                
                strFirst = Regex.Split(lhs.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
                strFirst = Regex.Split(lhs.ToString().Replace("|", ">>"), "([0-9]+)");
                Value.Add(lhs, strFirst);
            }

            if (!Value.TryGetValue(rhs, out strSecond))
            {
                strSecond = Regex.Split(rhs.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
                strSecond = Regex.Split(rhs.ToString().Replace("|", ">>"), "([0-9]+)");

                Value.Add(rhs, strSecond);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < strFirst.Length && i < strSecond.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!strFirst[i].Equals(strSecond[i]))
                {
                    return Splitcompare(strFirst[i], strSecond[i]);
                }
            }
            if (strSecond.Length > strFirst.Length)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (strFirst.Length > strSecond.Length)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        private static int Splitcompare(string left, string right)
        {
            int x, y;
            if (!int.TryParse(left.ToString(), out x))
            {
                return left.CompareTo(right);
            }

            if (!int.TryParse(right.ToString(), out y))
            {
                return left.CompareTo(right);
            }

            return x.CompareTo(y);
        }
   }
```

The above code gives me error, when I try to use Replace on Regex line. Reason being, I can't use string function on T.

Comment: Why do you want a generic version that works only on strings?

Comment: It compares objects using ToString(), which is not exactly working only on strings.

Comment: A generic type is used when it does not matter what the thing `T` actually is; its use as far as the class is concerned will actually be *generic*. If you're working with a generic type in .NET and find yourself concerned with the value it's a good sign that you're improperly using the construct.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Split()` returns a `string[]`, but you've defined `strFirst` and `strSecond` as the generic parameter type `T`. Try this instead:

```
private Dictionary<T, string[]> Value;

public BaseComparer()
{
    Value = new Dictionary<T, string[]>();
}

string[] strFirst, strSecond;

if (! Value.TryGetValue(lhs, out strFirst))
{                
    strFirst = Regex.Split(lhs.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
    strFirst = Regex.Split(lhs.ToString().Replace("|", ">>"), "([0-9]+)");
    Value.Add(lhs, strFirst);
}

if (! Value.TryGetValue(rhs, out strSecond))
{
    strSecond = Regex.Split(rhs.ToString().Replace(" ", ""), "([0-9]+)");
    strSecond = Regex.Split(rhs.ToString().Replace("|", ">>"), "([0-9]+)");
    Value.Add(rhs, strSecond);
}
```

Comment: You'd also have to update the `Dictionary<T, T[]> Value` as you would no longer be storing a `T[]` but a `string[]`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair You're right, I'll update for that. This also leads to the same question of whether this should be a generic type. IMO it probably shouldn't.

Comment: Probably not. It may as well just take `object` at this point.(although as a generic, it may avoid value-type boxing, but somehow I doubt that that would be the bottleneck for performance in this method) The comparison can be made non-generic in a static class, but if this is still to implement `IComparer<T>` it would still have to be generic on the `BaseComparer<T>` level before being casted to `object` and passed into the non-generic static helper method.

Comment: @Yuck, I tried doing exactly the same thing, but it didn't worked. As per what Chris said, that means, it would not be a wise decision to convert my compare routine to generic? If yes, why?